# AngularJS and Ionic click to repeat a failed http request

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, error-handling, ionic-framework

I'm making an app using AngularJS and Ionic.

When my app sends a request to the server using $http and fails, I want a view to load to show the user a button which, when clicked, repeats the $http request that was just attempted.

Currently if the request fails, it will load an error view, but I want that error view to have a button which performs a repeated task when clicked. This will be the same error controller for all server errors, so needs to be adaptable and have a way to pass in or repeat all functions easily in one place.

```
   function getData(){
        $http({
          url: remoteUrl+'/dat/get_data_app',
          method: 'POST',
          data: {}
        }).then(function(response) {


        }, function(response) {
          //the getData is trying to pass in the current function so it can be repeated in the error controller
          $localstorage.setObject('httpObj', getData());
          $state.go('app.error');

        }); 
    }
```

Below is the error controller currently:

```
  .controller('ErrorCtrl', function($scope, $localstorage, $recipes) {
      var httpObj = $localstorage.getObject('httpObj');
      //this needs to run as a funtion (only when button is clicked but I can sort that out, just need a way of passing the function here)
      httpObj;

    })
```

The error controller runs when the user lands on the error page. In order to make the controller short and not need much changing later, I want the function passed here to run on click of a button which I'll place here.

Adding the button isn't the problem, but I just want to know if there's an easy way to pass the function.

This whole way of doing it may be wrong but any thoughts will be appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: couldn't you create a custom directive and pass the function name to the error controller that way?